# How to vertically center \textbf{.}?

Tags: bullets

This MWE is close but not exact :

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\cdot$\raisebox{2pt}{\textbf{.}}$\cdot$
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the problem with `$\bm{\cdot}$` (with `\usepackage{bm}`)?

Comment: doesn't work for some reason

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\cdot\vcenter{\hbox{\textbf{.}}}\cdot$ but what is that good for, or why is it
better than \verb|\boldsymbol|: $\cdot\boldsymbol{\cdot}\cdot$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i couldn't get `\boldsymbol` to work

Comment: @RandyRanderson but in my answer it works.... or can't you load `amsmath`?

Comment: i don't know. the first thing works. it's for lists

Comment: @RandyRanderson Please note that the first thing is not perfectly aligned with `\cdot` and also depends on what you put around it. I'm using `\vcenter` mainly for putting diagrams into equations. But it might work well with lists. Other options include tiny bullets.

Comment: It's close enough. Don't know why `\bm` doesn't work.

Comment: It will make letters bold but not `\cdot`

Comment: I think the `mathabx` package is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Just a kludge but this works

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 \phantom{x}
 \vfill
$\cdot$\raisebox{2pt}{\textbf{.}}$\cdot$
\vfill
 \phantom{x}
\end{document}
```

To get the exact page center vice text space then you have to adjust margins and footer and header size.